# Asp.Net How to Get Expires Date or Max Age of Cookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

I want to get AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie's expires date to show user. I set that cookie's options but now need to see how much times left. I will put that time to navbar.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});
```

I tried something like that but can only access cookie's id, cant access expires or max date. How can I do that?

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
@{
    var cookie = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie.expires?view=net-7.0) , try to use Cookie.Expires Property.